# Is there a way to undraw the bow without firing it?

Tags: far-cry-3

Sometimes I get a little twitchy and pull back an arrow I'm not really ready to fire.

**Is there a way to un-draw the bow without firing the arrow?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pressing the reload button* will cancel bow drawing without firing the arrow.

* <kbd>R</kbd> -  PC

<kbd>□</kbd> - PS3

**Ⓧ** - Xbox 360